# Setting libraries in Windows Explorer to expanded by default

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'd like files in two of my libraries to be expanded by default. That is, when I open up Windows explorer I'd like to see these two libraries expanded, showing the directories within them. If relevant I am running 64 bit Windows 7 SP1.